# Making JSPlumb enabled divs draggable with an on/off button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

http://jsfiddle.net/taoist/fsmX7/

In the code example above I would like the default state of the .textDivContainer to **not** be draggable. Then when the user clicks the green button I want the editor to close (which it does) and I would like the  **.textDivContainer** to be draggable. Then once the user clicks the button again the editor would open and the div would **not** be draggable hence creating a toggle switch.  As it stands this does not work.

However, I do have it working *without* JsPlumb using the default JQuery draggable method.
This is viewable below.

The Draggable method in the Non-JSPlumb JSfiddle *below* accomplishes this by using 2 different property values titled "enable" and "disable". These do *not* seem to work with JSPlumb. I attempted to use those two properties with JSplumb to no avail. They might work but if so I am lost as to how to implement them.

http://jsfiddle.net/KrdEU/5/

Below is the final JSFiddle thus far which is a semi-working JSplumb version. This uses a class swap to implement the draggable feature. It defaults to non-draggable and when the green button is clicked it becomes draggable. However, when the green button is clicked a second time it does *not* stop the draggable.

http://jsfiddle.net/taoist/fsmX7/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {


var dragToggle = null ;
    $(".textButton1"). mousedown(function(){

        if (dragToggle===null){
        dragToggle = '.textDivContainer1';  

        }

        else if (dragToggle === '.textDivContainer1'){
        dragToggle=null;
        }

        console.log(dragToggle);


        jsPlumb.draggable($(dragToggle), { snap: true});


        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

Use **setDraggable(el, draggable)**

http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/files/jsPlumb-1.4.1-apidoc.html#jsPlumb.setDraggable(el,draggable)

Comment: Anyone know what this page had, or an example of what was on the page because now the link leads to a 404 error.

Comment: https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_setDraggable